# Why can't I post on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, monthly-question-limit

I am getting this error - reached the 50-questions limit with only six questions? And I just opened my account today.

Comment: do you have your cookies disabled?

Comment: Are you on a shared internet connection, such as a university?  If it notices a lot of connections from your IP it may think that you're creating lots of accounts to get around the question limit.

Comment: I'm not seeing _any_ questions from you. Can you link to your profile page?

Comment: (As an aside: posting the *exact* error message is always useful.)

Comment: I am using it at work. With a number of others

Comment: One of your co-workers has been abusing the site pretty badly, @gitman. If you're on good terms with the guy who's asked 50 questions using two accounts in the past month, you might want to have a talk with him about spoiling it for the rest of you.

Comment: How can we address this issue

Comment: I been asking around and no one knows about the limit

Comment: The person who needs to know about it should become aware of it next time he logs in or checks his email.

Comment: Put how can we address it so we can used the service